# Codeigniter select always return top row data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the `cus mobile` from the `tbl_customer_registration` where `cus_email` that passe from `$email`.

On other words I want to get the **customer mobile** where **customer email** equals to  `$email`

```
$this->db->select("tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile");
$this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
$this->db->where('tbl_customer_registration.cus_email', $email);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
  return $query->row_array();
} else {
  return NULL;
}
```

[image]

**It always return the first row of the** `tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile`

Here is what they return it is not cus_mobile what I need

```
Array
(
  [session_id] => ecf905ab051376563d3ce4140716d818
  [ip_address] => ::1
  [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
  [last_activity] => 1404446526
  [user_data] => 
  [mobile] => 0712641946
  [user_name] => podijobs@gmail.com
  [is_logged_in] => 1
  [cart_contents] => Array
  (
    [66eeaa0e65f3bf68db770c4c1b29891e] => Array
    (
      [rowid] => 66eeaa0e65f3bf68db770c4c1b29891e
      [id] => SP004
      [qty] => 1
      [price] => 1500
      [name] => Vegi Pizza Big
      [image] => pizza-buena.jpg
      [subtotal] => 1500
    )
    [total_items] => 1
    [cart_total] => 1500
  )
)
```

Comment: That should work. Though the return will be an array with key cus_mobile and value 071....

Comment: Thank you for the reply .It return some other value not what I need

Comment: please use var_dump( $query->row_array() ) ou print_r ( $query->row_array() ) and show us the results outputed

Comment: This query returns what?

Comment: It return the first row of the tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the function result() or result_array() in order to return a query result like:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['cus_mobile'];
}
```

in case you are expecting only one row to be returned you can also use the function row() like:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
  $row = $query->row();
  echo $row->cus_mobile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply fist foreach return all cus_mobile from the db and second code return the my old result.